# Mootools popup not staying closed when navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, cookies

Ive been struggling with this popup, I would like it to appear to a new visitor (30 days cookie) only once, currently it is almost working - it appears each time you change the page however I would like for it to remain closed for the cookie duration no matter which page the user navigated too.

You can see an example here - www.marktoe.co.za and the code below

HTML:

```
<div id = "theLink"><?php if($this->countModules('tekenin2')) : ?>
<div id="gototop">
<div id="popup"><a href="#" onclick="parentNode.remove();return false; ">
<img src="/templates/marktoe/images/close.png" id="close" class="close" border="0" alt="close" /></a>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="tekenin2" style="xhtml" />
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?></div>


div#theLink {
width: 500px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 99999999;
top: 15%;
left: 35%;
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}
div#popup {
border: 2px solid #8CC34A;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #FFF;
width: 500px;
opacity: 0.95;
margin: 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
#popup img.close {
float: right;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
.moduletable-nlpopup {
margin: 0;
padding: 70px 0 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top leftpx;
border: none;
}
.moduletable-nlpopup h3 {
}
a.toplink {
font-size:10px;
}
#gototop {
font-size:10px;
width:500px;
font-size:11px;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0px;
height: 300px;
}
#gototop:hover {

}
```

Cookie:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function setTheDivStyle() {// body on load event
if(!readCookie('wroteIt')) {

// if cookie not found display the div and create the cookie
document.getElementById("theLink").style.display="none";
createCookie('wroteIt', 'wroteIt', 1);  // 1 day = 24 hours persistence
}
else {
// if cookie found hide the div
document.getElementById("theLink").style.display="block";
}
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, as I said Ive been struggling with this a while now but cookies are not my strongpoint.
Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas anyone? Sorry to bump this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem which was relating to a scroll spy plugin I was using which was relaunching the pop up each time a new page loaded - have since removed scrollspy and the behavior works like a dream now.